# How to call a method from an action which is referring the attribute tag for class name in ADF

Tags: java, jsf, oracle-adf

I have a use case like there is a af:train component which will be part of a template.

I am using this template for creating the pages which are defined inside a bounded task flow which is a train

My template looks like this

```
 <f:facet name="bottom">
                    <af:toolbar id="pt_t1">
                        <af:button id="tt_b1" rendered="#{attrs.backRendered}"
                                   action="#{controllerContext.currentViewPort.taskFlowContext.trainModel.getPrevious}"
                                   text="Back" disabled="#{attrs.backDisabled}"/>
                        <af:button id="tt_b2" rendered="#{attrs.nextRendered}"
                                   action="#{controllerContext.currentViewPort.taskFlowContext.trainModel.getNext}"
                                   text="Next" disabled="#{attrs.nextDisabled}"/>
                        <af:button text="Cancel" id="pt_b1"
                                   actionListener="#{tabLauncher_backing.closeCurrentActivity}"/>
                        <af:button text="Finish" id="pt_b2"  
                                   action="#{attrs.backingBean.showMessage}"
                                   disabled="#{attrs.finishDisabled}"/>
                    </af:toolbar>
                </f:facet>
```

Inside the same template itself I have declared the **backingBean** attribute as shown below

```
  <afc:attribute>
                <afc:attribute-name>backingBean</afc:attribute-name>
                <afc:attribute-class>java.lang.Object</afc:attribute-class>
            </afc:attribute>
```

So In the page where I need to set the backingBean value to some class I will set it as shown below

```
<f:attribute name="backingBean" value="com.example.Page3"/>
```

In the first code you can see there is  Finish button which is calling the method showMessage as defined in the action of that button.

Now whenever run my application and click on the Finish button it shows the below **error message**:

```
Template.jspx @22,76 action="#{attrs.backingBean.showMessage}": Method not found: com.example.Page3.showMessage()
```

By the way the method showMessage is there inside Page3 class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After setting the values of the **backingBean** in the page as shown below :

```
 <f:attribute name="backingBean" value="#{pageFlowScope.backingPage3}"/>
```

it is working !!!  and the expression  should be in the above format itself....

**Note**: *backingPage3 managed bean should be declared inside the particular taskflow in which the page using the template is placed*

Comment: odd. I answered your question but you did not upvote me.

Comment: Thanks for the upvote ;-) I have added some additional detail that may help you as well.

Answer (score 1):

Why attrs.backingBean.showMessage instead of a memory scope like pageFlowScope or request? I think attrs is for text strings only for templates. I think your bean needs a scope and can then be called. by default it's request scope.
To be more complete: One must choose a memory scope for one's bean. Read more [here](http://www.software-architect.net/blog/article/date/2014/05/26/cheat-sheet-oracle-adf-bean-memory-scopes.html).

Also, a Managed Bean is usually registered with the Unbounded Task Flow: adfc-config and is then available to all other task flows in the that application. If you are making Task Flows reusable and sharing them with other developer,s *then* registering a managed bean needed in that Task Flow is done. Otherwise adfc-config is the better choice.

Also, be aware that better practice is to *not* use the specific memory scope with the bean ex: #{pageFlowScope.Bean.method}.
and instead allow ADF Faces to look for and figure out where the bean is - it starts with request scope and goes form there: ex: #{Bean.method}
When you hard code the scope into the bean reference, then if it is not found there, you get an NPE.
Example: `In the case of this code: #{requestScope.dispalyBean.incidents}
This is not working because it makes a fundamental mistake in understanding of JSF expression language.  By explicitly asking for the “requestScope” prefix you are stating that the bean already exists and can be found on the request scope already - hence it is never corrected.  If you amend your EL to #{dispalyBean.incidents} where displayBean is defined as a request scope bean then JSF will detect that the bean does not exist yet and then create it.`